# How can ı fix error of TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, python-webbrowser

I assigned the website link I got from the database to a variable and I want to open this variable with the webbrowser module, but it gives an error

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="password",database="database")
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("select spotify_link from users where user_name=%s",[login_user_name_entry.get()])
spotify_link=cursor.fetchone()

def open_profile_spotify_link():
    if spotify_link==None:
        messagebox.showerror("Error",message="No link information has been entered here by the user")
    else:
        webbrowser.open(spotify_link)
```

I want the link that I assigned to the variable to be opened, how can I do it?

the error i got : TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple

Comment: Does `webbrowser.open(spotify_link[0])` work?

Comment: yea it's worked thanks 
can you explain why you add [0]?

Comment: `fetchone` returns a `tuple`, in this case containing a single element. `spotify_link[0]` returns the first element in the tuple.